# How to display the page after all the automation is completed in Playwright

Tags: python, automation, playwright

I am creating an automation task using Playwright and Python. I have a web page and I am doing certain actions there. At first page is opened as headless, but I want to see the results after all the steps are completed. I looked through the documentation but haven't found anything useful.

Comment: If you don´t need to rely on python, I recommend using NodeJS. NodeJS is always in advance compared to Python and other languages. NodeJS already provides a build-in reporter https://playwright.dev/docs/test-reporters. The reporter can be configured that it records videos of all steps which you can watch afterward. https://playwright.dev/docs/videos

Comment: How about taking a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new context with headless=False and opening a new page when needed.

```
browser = p.chromium.launch(headless=True)
context = browser.new_context()

# Perform automation tasks in headless mode

context = browser.new_context(headless=False)
```